# Automount of AFP shares on Lion clients from OS X Snow Leopard server - not working right

Tags: macos, networking, afp

Recently upgraded Snow Leopard clients to Lion. AFP shares are set up as login items. The network shares on some of the machines now take a long time to come up (10 minutes). Several machines that were upgraded are acting normally, and three machines with clean installs of Lion (not upgraded) are also working normally. Is there a network file causing a conflict on some of these client machines?
Thanks, Paul

Comment: We have Snow Leopard Server and a support contract with Apple which Expires November 2012. I enquired when our Mountain Lion clients would not connect to the AFP user and group shares which did work under SL. I looked in console and it showed a issue with permissions. We have not yet solved it and currently can only mount our AD user areas for the moment.